# Session End firing in Application Start Up

Tags: asp.net, sessionend

In my ASP.NET Application, the Session_End method is firing when Application starts up. My break points in that method hits when app starts for the first time.
Isn't it supposed to execute only after Session was timed out? why is this weird behavior.

Am i missing something.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it firing when the app starts? Or when it *restarts*?

Comment: I am not sure if its firing on restart but when app starts for the first time it does fire and why does it so as its intended to fire on session end  ..driving me crazy